# How to know keypresses using X11 in C++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, keyboard, x11

## My Goal:

I'm making **C++** programs but something very important is missing,
the program needs to **know which key is pressed** but I don't know any way to do it.

## Problems:

After some researches, the most native way of getting key presses seems to be using **X11**.
Everything about keyboard input the [**Xlib** manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/)  were using events,
but **I don't know how to handle events!**

**Is there any way to know key presses without using events?

Or how to use X11 events?**

If any clarification is needed, please add a comment or suggest an edit

Comment: https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/ has both an explanation of what events are, how to handle them using an event loop, and an example you can hack on. `xcb_wait_for_event (connection)` would be the your `GetPressedKey()`, with some post-processing to determine the event flavor. Note that this is XCB instead of Xlib, as the modern implementations of Xlib on Linux delegate to XCB anyway.

Comment: curses can do that: http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There are two (and more) ways to achieve it:

#### The Unrecommended Hard Way

It does the required features but is not recommended as it is slower and uses more lines of code.

```cpp
uint32_t PressedKeys[8];

bool RefreshPressedKeys() {
  while(XPending(X11Display)) {
    XEvent KeyEvent;
    XNextEvent(X11Display,&KeyEvent);
    if(KeyEvent.type==KeyPress) {
      uint32_t KeyEventCode=KeyEvent.xkey.keycode;
      for(uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++) {
        if(PressedKeys[i]==0) {
          PressedKeys[i]=KeyEventCode;
          break;
        }
      }
    }else if(KeyEvent.type==KeyRelease) {
      uint32_t KeyEventCode=KeyEvent.xkey.keycode;
      for(uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++) {
        if(PressedKeys[i]==KeyEventCode) {
          PressedKeys[i]=0;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

uint32_t GetAPressedKey() { //Get a pressed key, won't always the last pressed key
  for(uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++) {
    if(PressedKeys[i]!=0) return PressedKeys[i]; //Returns the first pressed key found
  }
  return 0; //Or 0 when no key found
}

bool IsKeyPressed(uint32_t KeyFilter) { //Is Key Pressed?
  for(uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++) {
    if(PressedKeys[i]==KeyFilter) return true; //Returns true if the key is pressed
  }
  return false; //Else false
}

int main() {
  uint8_t Key;
  XSelectInput(X11Display,X11Window,KeyPressMask|KeyReleaseMask); //Enables keyboard input
  while(1) {
    Key = GetPressedKey(); //Gets the pressed key's number
    std::cout << Key << '\n'; //Displays the number
    /* Some code using the Key var */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### The Recommended Easy Way

The program **might be more complex** to understand at first but **it's better** since it can theoretically handle an *"infinite"* number of keys pressed at once.

```cpp
int main() {
  XSelectInput(Pixel.GetX11Display(),Pixel.GetX11Window(),KeyPressMask|KeyReleaseMask);
  while(1) {
    while(XPending(Pixel.GetX11Display())) { //Repeats until all events are computed
      XEvent KeyEvent;
      XNextEvent(Pixel.GetX11Display(),&KeyEvent); //Gets exactly one event
      if(KeyEvent.type==KeyPress) {
        uint32_t KeyEventCode=KeyEvent.xkey.keycode; //Gets the key code, NOT HIS CHAR EQUIVALENT
        std::cout << KeyEventCode << '\n'; //Displays the key code

        /* Code handling a Keypress event */

      } else if(KeyEvent.type==KeyRelease) {
         uint32_t KeyEventCode=KeyEvent.xkey.keycode;
         std::cout << KeyEventCode << '\n'; //Displays the key code

         /* Code handling a KeyRelease event */

      }
    }

    /* General code */

  }
}
```

These two programs were handwritten by me; I may have made an error since I haven't tested them, but it should be something similar.

These are copyleft and you don't need to credit me :)

Please comment or suggest an edit for any error found or for code clarification.

Comment: I figured out I should use the second way since it's better in every stats: more versatile, better "no key pressed support", better key release support, catch up to an *"infinite"* amount of keys, easier for what I do and *faster*.

Comment: An easier way could be to use [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [FLTK](https://fltk.org/)